# How to georeference a radar PNG/GIF in Python

Tags: python, georeferencing

I have this data (image attached). I need to georeference it using the data available in the image itself.
Additionally I have one pair of coordinates for the said image provided.
17.74811366,83.34555159
How to go about it, I need the final output as a GeoTIFF.

I'm trying to use GDAL, but being new to Python I don't know what the exact algorithm should look like.

[image: radar image from IMD]

Comment: I have the central coordinates and the pixel resolution(as shown in image), I should be able to calculate the edge coordinates based on the size of the image?

Comment: Yes. You also need to know its CRS. The best practice is to calculate the corner coordinates.

Comment: Okay, let's assume I have 4 coordinates calculated manually. What should the code look like?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=georeferencing+png

Comment: https://rasha-salim.medium.com/georeferencing-images-in-python-ddd2cf8b59ea